# Android light and fast way to implement data storage from Api Rest service

Tags: android, json, rest, local-storage

I'd have to implement a simple app that retrieves some data from Api Rest service through JSON and save them to internal data storage.

Until now, I'm using AsynTask custom class for each call but it seems a complicated and slow process to retrieve json, check, parse and save it to storage ( I'm usic DBHelper with an SQLLite DB ).

I don't need to manage a large amount of data, I need to manage events with some strings, an image url, and some dates.
The important is having a fast process to load/update/storage/retrieve information from API Rest Service to android internal storage.

What is the best solution to implement it?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Don't reinvent the wheel and use successful libraries for API / database handling. This will save you tons of (debugging) time. Have a look at the [Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/) for the libraries fitting your needs. For a clean architecture have a look at [these samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

To get information from RestApi I would recommend a [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It let you get data very easy and convert it to lot's of different format.

If you will use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) then retrofit can convert your data from server directly to objects. And then just sabe this objects to you local db.

Different ORM libraries let you do that very easy.